# WMS alternative in win server 2012

Tags: windows, streaming, iis, windows-server-2012, video-streaming

- WMS is not present in win server 2012, so what alternative we have to support streaming video files.
- Are there any DLLs available to do this.
- Where to find info about this, plz give me some pointers.
- win 2012 have IIS 8.5

thx

Comment: IIS Media Services (http://www.iis.net/media) is the replacement for WMS, not a drop in replacement and some features may be missing, for example multicast support.

Comment: thx Brian. I found a link (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40837). what is the difference b/w essential media pack and IIS Media Services.

Comment: Media pack is for streaming over the local network using DLNA. IIS Media Services for streaming over the Internet to Silverlight or other clients.

Comment: hi Brain, MS Expression Encoder is required as a part for streaming, on this site (http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=18974) they say that Encoder 4 does not support live IIS Smooth Streaming for live streaming upgrade to Expression Encoder Pro. And here (http://www.microsoft.com/expression/eng/) MS says that Expression Encoder 4 Pro is no longer available for sale. So does this means that we dont have any support for live streaming in Microsoft Expression Encoder ??

Comment: You would need to get one of the third party encoding solutions listed in the article you linked.

Comment: Hello Brian plz comment on it if you have any idea (http://superuser.com/questions/832617/publishing-points-in-iis-8-5-on-windows-2012)